# Android Kotlin Executing SQLite query in MainActivity

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to execute a SQL query from my MainActivity. I'm currently using a large portion of [this example](https://grokonez.com/android/kotlin-sqlite-example-crud-operations-with-listview-android). Upon clicking my Acknowledge button, it finds the selected rows, gets the jsonID of said row, then I'm wanting to update a value in my SQLite table of those rows.

So my question is, how do I execute my "jsonQuery" string, to my SQLite database upon clicking my Acknowledge button?

Here's the code I have in my MainActivity:

```
acknowledge.setOnClickListener {

        var jsonData_text: String = ""

        for (i in 0 until JSONParser.MrAdapter.public_modelArrayList!!.size) {
            if (JSONParser.MrAdapter.public_modelArrayList!!.get(i).getSelecteds()) {
                jsonData_text = jsonData_text + JSONParser.MrAdapter.public_modelArrayList!!.get(i).getJSONID() + ","
            }
        }

        val jsonSQLQuery = jsonData_text.dropLast(1)
        val jsonQuery = "update Notes set acknowledged = 1 WHERE jsonID in ("+jsonSQLQuery+")"
        Log.d("logged_json", jsonQuery)

    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1.) this is clearly not a [minimal verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 2.) my goodness the author of that tutorial had no idea about Kotlin. You're not supposed to have to type `!!`s almost ever. `var` should be used sparingly. Mutable lists should be constrained to be private (`List<T>` instead of `ArrayList<T>`). There is no reason to write `constructor() {}` block just to do field assignments. And so on. 3.) The code is just generally bad. The author loads the database synchronously on UI thread in `onResume()` (which runs after loss of window focus)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as you can see, I'm quite a newbie of Kotlin. Are there any similar tutorials you can recommend yourself? The code I have now, despite it being bad, still accomplishes what I want for now except being able to execute a SQL query on MainActivity, is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not blaming you, you were following a tutorial you couldn't have known was bad.  I have a guide for Kotlin: https://github.com/Zhuinden/guide-to-kotlin/wiki/6.)-Anti-Patterns but I don't have one "generally for Android development". As for DB things, you should probably read through https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0 and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0 and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html/#0 and https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

Comment: Thanks for the guide and DB links, they should help me a ton!